# JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I just upgraded to Boot 1.4.1 which itself upgrades to SDR 2.5.3. This introduces JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator which kicks in when e.g. a Pageable is used in a RequestMapping-method in a @RepositoryRestController.

This tries to find out the used Repository from the request path and do then some translations.

My problem is, that I have a @RepositoryRestController which is not bound to a particular repository but finds it repo based on the request path like /{collection}/query.

This now failes because SDR cannot find the repository.

So my question is: How can I solve this?
I have to use @RepositoryRestController because I need a PersistentEntityResourceAssembler injected as method param. So Using just @Controller does not work.

Do I have to implement my own version of Pageable and translate it into the SD-Pageable?
Can I disable JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

jackson-annotations-2.3.5.jar, 
jackson-core-2.3.5.jar, 
jackson-databind-2.3.5.jar

```
<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="formHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Hm, was this an answer to my question? ;)

Comment: hey, did you ever managed to solve this?